# How to create element dynamically within another element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, append, appendchild

I am trying to append a newly created paragraph element to the main section of my HTML.
I have created the paragraph element and appended text to it. I am now trying to add this element to the main id of the HTML. My console does not show any error messages, but this element has not been added to my HTML. I appreciate any feedback!

```js
let newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
let newParagraphText = document.createTextNode("ipsom lorem");

newParagraph.appendChild(newParagraphText);

let results = document.querySelector("#results");

results.appendChild(newParagraph);
```

```html
<main id="results"></main>
```

Comment: It works, take a look at your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the issue. All of the code worked as it should, I just had to move my script tag to the bottom of the HTML file.